# Pyqt5 - Paint event not being called when view moves too quickly

Tags: python, pyqt5, paint, qgraphicsview, qgraphicsscene

I have a PyQt5 application which shows a window containing some items and a ruler on both sides.
For example:

[image: example image]

The structure of the application is as follows:
The widget containing the `QGraphicsView` places it in a `QSplitter` which is placed inside the `QHBoxLayout` of the widget.
The QGraphicsView has a QGraphicsScene which is added using `setScene` . The size of the scene is set using:
`self.setSceneRect(QtCore.QRectF(self.contentsRect()))`

The scene contains the two rulers which are `QGraphicsRectItem` with custom `paint` methods. These are added using the `addItem` method of the scene.

When the user right clicks the view and drags their mouse the scene location is updated. This is done by storing the initial mouse position at the `mousePressEvent`, and translating the view during the `mouseMoveEvent`. The scene is moved using the `setSceneRect` method.

The issue that I have is that if the user moves their mouse too quickly, the  rulers will get outside the drawing region and will not be redrawn untill the user moves the other direction to capture them again.

**What I've tried:**

- Calling `update`, `prepareGeometryUpdates` and `invalidate` on the rulers.
- Calling the `render` and `repaint` methods on the `QGraphicsView` every time a move is executed.

**What works**:
I can get it to update by creating a `QPainter` and calling the `paint` event of the rulers manually when the view is updated. However, this raises a bunch of PyQt warnings.

**Code Example**:
Due to the large amount of code involved for a minimal working example, I tried to write it as clear as possible above. Please let me know if anything is unclear .

Comment: Sorry, but your explanation is too vague to understand the problem and we cannot really do wild guesses. Please take your time and provide a valid [mre].

Comment: Is it possible for me to add a file? Because then I can create a small application and zip it to share it iwth you. I'm afraid that it will be a lot of code for a code block (and a hassle with all different files).

Comment: No, you cannot add files, and you do not have to share the whole program. As explained above, you have to provide a MRE, which is a basic example written with the smallest possible amount of code while still allowing us to *reproduce* the problem: we should be able to copy, paste and run it without any substantial modifications, and be able to focus on the problem, without being distracted by irrelevant aspects that are not related to the issue at hand. It will take some amount of time and efforts to do it, but that's the only way we can actually help you.

Comment: As explained above, I'm afraid it will be a lot of code for a code block. I'll see if I can get it in there anyway.